# When using an icon font such as FontAwesome, how do I make the icons bindable in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

With [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/), I want to use the *icon-remove* icon. So I have `<i class="icon-remove"></i>` in my HTML, which works perfectly. However, I wanted to make this bindable in jQuery to close a div for me.

So I used:

```
    $(".icon-remove").click(function() {
        alert("HELLO");
        $(".login-window").hide();
        $(".register-window").hide();
        $(".shadow").hide();
    });
```

However, this doesn't work. When I click it, nothing happens.

This is the CSS I've used (also of note: `cursor: pointer;` doesn't work).

```
.icon-remove {
    display: block;

    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the icon was added dynamically after page load, that click event won't work. You need to use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

Here's one way of using it:

```
$(document).on("click", ".icon-remove", function() {
    alert("HELLO");
    $(".login-window").hide();
    $(".register-window").hide();
    $(".shadow").hide();
});
```

Comment: Ok, well in that case the next step is to check for errors like Leniel suggested, and post any that you find. If you don't find any errors you will need to either post more of the code or give a working demo.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is OK. Maybe you have some error in your JavaScript code that is preventing the whole thing to work. Using Firebug on Firefox for example, you can check the Console tab to see if there's an error in your code.

Here's the JS Bin to test your code: http://jsbin.com/obogof/4

For the `CSS` part, you must be sure that your CSS code comes after any other CSS rules that affect the `.icon-remove` class. It works correctly here: http://jsbin.com/obogof/5

Comment: No other rule affects the `.icon-remove` class. :/

Comment: It's entirely possible that I'm just not using the console properly, but no, when I click nothing appears in the console.

Comment: Uhmm... with Firebug open in the Console tab: reload the entire page. Generally it will show the errors (if any) at this time.

Comment: Okay, I have Firebug open, refreshed page with Console tab open, and nothing displays.

Comment: So, the last question: Are you sure you have jQuery linked correctly? In Firebug look at the Scripts tab and open the dropdown... look for jQuery file there.

Answer (score 0):

Is your javascript executing after the DOM is ready? You will need the following:

```
$(document).on("click", ".icon-remove", function() {
    alert("HELLO");
    $(".login-window").hide();
    $(".register-window").hide();
    $(".shadow").hide();
});
```